# Spring expression (SpEL) - Elvis operator : cannot convert from Integer to Boolean error

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am using Spring expression version 4.3.2.RELEASE
It seems we cannot use the Elvis operator for any other types than String and Boolean.

For example, the following will thrown an error:
field ?: 2 > 0

- If field = 1 we get
  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
- If field is null:
  then Elvis works correctly and use the value 2.

Can we work around this?  is it a defect in SpEL?

thanks,

Sebastien

Comment: What is your field type?Integer?

Comment: hi yes it is an Integer in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elvis operator is shorthand notation for ternary operator, used in case of **nullability** check.

Its syntax is:

```
someField?:somevalue
```

where, someField can be of any type. Above expression will return value of `someField (e.g. Integer)`, if it's not `null` else it will return `someValue`. someValue must be of same type as `someField (Integer)`.

So, This is not a limitation of SPel. It is the specific usage of operator.

In your example, `field` is an integer so, resolved value must also be of integer type. But, you are doing `2>0` that resolves to boolean type, which is not valid in this case.

What you can do is `(field?: 2) > 0`, if it is what you are trying to achieve.

I hope, it clarifies.

Comment: @Sebastien Great. Glad i could help.

Comment: @Sebastien You can mark the answer as done for others.

Comment: Thanks. This is the write answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an operator precedence issue. Maybe your expression should be `(field ?: 2)>0`

Hope it helps.